# strings.Contains() returns always false

Tags: string, go, compare, contains

In Go, I want to check if the following string contains `text/plain` in a string. The function [strings.Contains()](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Contains) returns always `false`.

My local go version is *go1.14.3 windows/amd64*, my server version is *go1.13.3 linux/amd64*

**Test code ([play.golang.org/p/_ikCzWd6438](https://play.golang.org/p/_ikCzWd6438))**

```
var test = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"

fmt.Println("my string:", test)
fmt.Println("strings.Contains(text/plain)", strings.Contains("text/plain", test))
fmt.Println("strings.Contains(text)", strings.Contains("text", test))
fmt.Println("strings.Contains(charset)", strings.Contains("charset", test))

var test2 = strings.ReplaceAll(test, "/", "") // remove slash
fmt.Println("my second string:", test2)
fmt.Println("strings.Contains(textplain)", strings.Contains("textplain", test2))
fmt.Println("strings.Contains(text)", strings.Contains("text", test2))
fmt.Println("strings.Contains(charset)", strings.Contains("charset", test2))
```

**Output**

```
my string: text/plain; charset=utf-8
strings.Contains(text/plain) false
strings.Contains(text) false
strings.Contains(charset) false
my second string: textplain; charset=utf-8
strings.Contains(textplain) false
strings.Contains(text) false
strings.Contains(charset) false
```

So why returns `strings.Contains()` always 'false'?

Comment: Your argument order for `Contains` is wrong. Use `Contains(test,"text/plain")

Comment: @Burak Shame on me. You're right!

Comment: Note that you should never use `contains` to test a media type. It will lead to false positives. Someone might be using a media type of 'customtext/plain` or `text/plain+mycustomizations` or even `image/jpeg; foo=text/plain` or any other combination of random things that will fool your logic, and still be valid. Instead, parse the media type properly using [`mime.ParseMediaType`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#ParseMediaType).

Comment: @flimzy I send a request to an external page and check if the target page is a text file (Content-Type text/plain). Some pages still have a charset in the content-type, so I only want to check if it is the content-type contains text/plain. This is only a small part of my test function.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. I'm saying that checking that the string contains will lead to false positives, so you should parse the media type correctly. `Content-Type: footext/plainbar`, `Content-Type: text/plain+custom`, and `Content-Type: image/jpeg; foo=text/plain` are all valid Content-Type values, and will all break your test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Contains):

> func Contains(s, substr string) bool
>
> Contains reports whether substr is within s.

The first parameter `s` is the original string and the second, `substr`, is the substring you search for. In your case, it is the other way around.

For example instead of `strings.Contains("charset", test)`, it should be `strings.Contains(test, "charset")`

Comment: Oh No.. That make sence :D

Comment: I upvoted question and answer, because yes, this is a stupid mistake to make - but I just made the same and for the life of me could not find what was wrong...